# Clearing the contents of a combobox in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform which has a few comboboxes with a list of options, what I would like to do is when the user clicks the close button that the text inside the comboboxes is cleared so that there are no pre-filled comboboxes. I have tried using the following but it does not work:

`Me.Combobox1.Clear`

To be clear I do not want to erase all of the options in the combobox, I would just like the option to be Null when the form is opened after someone has already used it.

Comment: Try `Me.Combobox1.ListIndex = -1`.

Comment: Also, `Me.Combobox1.Value = ""`